# C# Array error "Unexpected symbol '{' "

Tags: c#, arrays

I declared some array then got an error thath said "Unexpected symbol '{' ".

```
int[] array ;

void Start () {
    if (level == 1) {
        array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  //error here
    }else if (level == 2) {
        array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};  //error here
    }else if (level == 3) {
        array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    }
}
```

I change above code to this

```
array [0] = 1;
array [1] = 2;
...
```

but i want a simpler one like the first code, how?

Comment: Just do `array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use the above syntax at the time of declaration, you can't use it later.

If you want to use something similar than you can do:

```
array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

or

```
array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

But, at the time of declaration you can do:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; //this should compile fine
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like below :

```
array =new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

For initializing array